# T-Sql Join replicate each side

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let me present a simplified version of the data I have:

```
declare @cctbl table ([cc] [int]);
insert into @cctbl ([cc]) values (1),(2),(3);

declare @datetbl table ([dte] [date]);
insert into @datetbl ([dte]) values ('20180320'),('20180321'),('20180322');

declare @outtbl table ([cc] [int],[dte] [date]);
insert into @outtbl ([cc],[dte])
    select [c].[cc],[d].[dte]
    from @cctbl [c]
    full outer join @datetbl [d] on ...?
```

I've got these two lists and the output I need from the above example will be:

```
[cc]    [dte]
1       2018-03-20
1       2018-03-21
1       2018-03-22
2       2018-03-20
2       2018-03-21
2       2018-03-22
3       2018-03-20
3       2018-03-21
3       2018-03-22
```

How do I get there from my 2 separated columns?

Comment: I keep going back to collation, but from looking it up, collate means something entirely different in sql.

Comment: Cross join maybe?

Comment: omg you legend.

Comment: you should submit that as an answer so i can give you credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross join is what you're after I think

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CROSS or OUTER APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) for this.

Using your example data, the result is the same no matter which you use.

```
SELECT *
FROM @cctbl c
CROSS APPLY @datetbl d
ORDER BY c.cc
```

[image]

> CROSS APPLY returns only rows from the outer table that produce a
>   result set from the table-valued function. OUTER APPLY returns both
>   rows that produce a result set, and rows that do not, with NULL values
>   in the columns produced by the table-valued function.

[[DEMO]](http://rextester.com/FMWZ61940)

Comment: @dya - thanks, although I do have to say that `CROSS JOIN` is also a completely valid answer for your specific question since you've got no logical correlation between your tables. If a larger sample of data was given that actually showed there to be some sort of 'join-able' condition (that you also wanted to use), then you'd have to really consider which approach would work best for your situation. Good thing now is you have a few options to test against your data.